# BATCH: Sorting data in a single file to identify an established minimum value

Tags: sorting, batch-file

I am currently trying to create a batch file that will ping multiple game worlds at different addresses, output the results to a single file in a non-cluttered fashion and then sort through those and output an ideal game world based on latency.

I'm stuck on how exactly to have the file sort through the worlds average's and decide and report back to the user which world has the lowest average latency.

In the file which contains all the world values they are formatted as follows:

```
"World 1" 
Minimum = 98ms, Maximum = 100ms, Average = 98ms
```

The only value that matters here is the "Average", there are going to be about a hundred or so different worlds included in this file formatted in the same way this one is.

If anyone can think of a way of taking this data and having the prompt output the world number with the lowest "Average" I would greatly appreciate it because I'm stuck here....

Data in this file is gathered and separated with the following method

```
ping example.com -w 350 >> w1.txt
```

Each ping creates its own unique txt file with the full ping command logged. The relevant lines from each individual document are then taken and separated into a different singular file.

```
findstr "Average" w1.txt >> separated\world1.txt
echo "World 1 >> final.txt
type world1.txt >> final.txt
```

Full copy of original work is here https://pastebin.com/azSgzi4k

Comment: There's no need for sorting. You can determine the smallest value with just one pass through the data.

Comment: @Joey this is true at the moment but as i said there is going to be about a hundred or so different worlds and sorting through all of them manually in a text file would take far too long. I could also, instead of using a batch file just open command prompt, manually ping each location, write them down on paper and see which one has the lowest latency as well, but the point here is simplification :)

Comment: Whilst you may wish to protect your 'intellectual property', I'm assuming that the data file was also generated by running some form of `ping` command line code. It may be better to incorporate the parsing of the results with their creation routine instead of doing so after the fact. For that reason I ask that you consider including the code which generates the data by appending it as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46401511/edit).

Comment: @Compo You are correct, i have edited my original post with a little more explanation of how the rest of the file works, the reason i did not originally include it is because the method i am trying to use is probably horribly inefficient and i wanted to avoid anyone telling me i had to change the entire file around to work a different way... any help much appreciated though, the pastebin link will show the entirety of what i have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this, *and wait*, to take a look at it's output:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('2^>Nul Set World[') Do Set "%%A="
For /L %%A In (1,1,62) Do For /F "Tokens=9" %%B In (
    '2^>Nul Ping oldschool%%A.runescape.com -w 350') Do Set World[%%A]=%%B
>Final.txt Set World[
Start Final.txt
```

*`Final.txt` will be in the current directory.*

Comment: This is fantastic and accomplishes everything i was trying to do short of displaying the final decision in the console but i can do that easily myself, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Your approach involves too much manual labour
- the time it takes to evaluate the pings may render the results useless as the next run may get different routings with differing results.

This batch parses the ping results and builds an array with all relevant data sorted by average ms, finally storing to the file w.txt.

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\25\SO_46401511.cmd
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ms=+0
:: Clear variables
For /f "delims==" %%A in ('set _') Do Set "%%A="
:: Iterate oldschool[1..62].runescape.com
For /L %%L in (1,1,62) do (
    Set /A L=100+%%L
    Echo Processing !L:~-2!
    For /f "tokens=1-7 delims=[]:=, " %%A in (
        'ping oldschool%%L.runescape.com -w 350^|findstr /i "Pinging Packets Minimum" '
    ) do (
        If %%A equ Pinging Set _URL=%%L,%%B,%%C
        if %%A equ Packets Set _URL=!_URL!,%%C,%%E,%%G
        if %%A equ Minimum (Set AVG=%%F
            Set /A "AVG=10000+!AVG:~0,-2!"
            Set _W[!AVG:~-4!]!L:~-2!=!_URL!,%%B,%%D,%%F
            Echo Processed _W[!AVG:~-4!]!L:~-2!=!_URL!,%%B,%%D,%%F
        )
    )
)
>w.txt Set _W
```

Depending on your location and ISP you will get other results.

```
> type w.txt
_W[0008]12=12,l3deff6-bond0-2.jagex.com,62.67.0.102,4,4,0,8ms,9ms,8ms
_W[0008]27=27,l3deff5-bond0-4.jagex.com,62.67.0.113,4,4,0,8ms,9ms,8ms
_W[0008]43=43,l3deff5-bond0-6.jagex.com,62.67.0.115,4,4,0,8ms,10ms,8ms
_W[0008]44=44,l3deff6-bond0-6.jagex.com,62.67.0.106,4,4,0,8ms,9ms,8ms
_W[0009]04=4,l3deff6-bond0-1.jagex.com,62.67.0.101,4,4,0,9ms,10ms,9ms
_W[0009]28=28,l3deff6-bond0-4.jagex.com,62.67.0.104,4,4,0,9ms,10ms,9ms
_W[0009]35=35,l3deff5-bond0-5.jagex.com,62.67.0.114,4,4,0,9ms,10ms,9ms
_W[0009]36=36,l3deff6-bond0-5.jagex.com,62.67.0.105,4,4,0,9ms,10ms,9ms
_W[0009]59=59,l3deff5-bond0-8.jagex.com,62.67.0.117,4,4,0,9ms,10ms,9ms
_W[0009]60=60,l3deff6-bond0-8.jagex.com,62.67.0.108,4,4,0,9ms,11ms,9ms
```

Comment: This is only a guess but I'm assuming they're only running this so that they can choose which world will be best for them to visit, I'm not certain that the output is really that important to them!

Comment: @Compo Agreed. OTOH the `de` in all the faster URLs returned indicate that nearer locations (to my German base) are also faster while the slowest (and with packet loss) are all in the US - IMO a valuable information.

Comment: @Compo You are correct in your assumption, the tool I am trying to create is supposed to be a user friendly automatic tool that picks out the world with the lowest average response time and echo's that world back into the console. The other information will not necessarily be important to the intended user.

Comment: @LotPings This is a much better approach than I had originally been using I agree my original was too labor intensive but I am extremely new to this and was not aware that yours was an option. Is it possible in the output, to include the world number of the pinged world so that that figure can be used to identify each individual result instead of the IP pinged?